# Can I transition the airspace (pictured below) without 2-way communication?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, aeronautical-charts

[image]

If I wanted to fly over Beverly regional between 2600-3000ft, do I need to speak to anyone as I do so? I would be above the delta and below the bravo, but the sectional states I must ask for approval from approach (124.4) above 2500ft? If so, what airspace would that be?

Answer (score 18):

The class D airspace for Beverly Regional extends from the surface to 2600 ft. msl (inclusive).  So, if you are flying at 2500 ft. msl, up to and including 2600 ft. msl, you would contact Boston Approach on 124.4 instead of the Beverly Control Tower for approval to fly through the Class D airspace.

When you are above 2600 ft. msl, you are no longer in the Beverly Regional Class D airspace.  Since the note on the Sectional Chart you refer to applies to the Class D airspace, which ends at 2600 ft. msl, when you are above that altitude this note would no longer apply.

However, keep in mind that talking to ATC and receiving VFR traffic advisories is always an excellent idea especially in a busy airspace area like when you are near Boston.

Comment: Thanks that’s helpful - so the note saying to contact approach 124.4 would only apply between 2500-2600ft? Seems like a very narrow window to include a special note on the sectional but that’s my interpretation too

Comment: @user64561 If you are above 026 you *may* still contact Boston Approach on 124.4 (and as 757 said, calling them for traffic advisories is a good idea) but you no longer *have* to call them. Whenever you want to enter (transit) Class D airspace you must establish two-way comms with the controlling agency. Usually Tower is the controlling agency for the entire Class D airspace; the note on the chart is just telling you that if you are transiting AOA025 the controlling agency is Approach instead of Tower.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Not talking to anyone when flying in a _400 foot_ vertical sliver between Class D and Class B airspace sounds like a bad idea. Also, remember that you'll be _well_ inside the Mode C & ADS-B Out veil, so those are requirements regardless of who you do or don't talk to.